# Is there some syntactic sugar I can use to set a JS variable to "" if it's null?

Tags: javascript

I want to set a variable to an empty string in Javascript, a pretty routine thing. I just don't know how to do it without doing this:

```
if (existingnote==null) {
  existingnote = "";
}
```

Is there a faster or easier way?

Comment: Do you only want to take account of `null`? Currently `undefined` also passes.

Comment: Is `existingnote = existingnote || ""` enough? I know it also matches `undefined`, `0`, empty string and so on...

Comment: that's probably the best, shortest answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
existingnote = existingnote || "";
```

This checks for [truthy/falsy](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/), which may not be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just `null` to work this way, try

```
existingnote = (existingnote === null? "": existingnote);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is now shorthand for @DaveNewton answer

[Logical OR Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR_assignment)

```js
let existingnote = null

existingnote || = "";

console.log(existingnote)
```